# Refactor multiple or conditions with java8

Tags: java-8

I have a scenario to refactor multiple or conditions in if block with java8

```
private boolean isStatusAvailable(List<Hierarchy> hierarchyList, String status, int i) {
    return isContainsStatus(hierarchyList.get(i+1), status) || isContainsStatus(hierarchyList.get(i+1), ResultStatus.SUCCESS) || isContainsStatus(hierarchyList.get(i+1), ResultStatus.PEND);
}
private boolean isContains(Hierarchy hierarchy, String status) {
    return hierarchy.getStatus().contains(status);
}
public enum ResultStatus {
    SUCCESS,
    SUCCESS_PENDING,
    SUCCESS_SUMMARY,
    PEND
}
```

Is there any way to refactor the above code in java8?

Comment: You should decide whether the method is named `isContains` or `isContainsStatus` and whether it expects a `String` or an `enum`; it can’t be both at the same time. Further, that `i+1` looks fishy. What’s the rationale behind it and how is the caller expected to cope with that, pass `-1` to access the list’s first element? And perhaps the the object returned by `getStatus()` allows a better query than repeatedly polling, but how are we supposed to tell without knowing what it returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always the possibility to introduce a loop like:

```
private boolean isStatusAvailable(List<Hierarchy> hierarchyList, ResultStatus status, int i) {
  Hierarchy hierarchy = hierarchyList.get(i + 1);
  for (ResultStatus s : Arrays.asList(status, SUCCESS, PEND)) {
    if (isContainsStatus(hierarchy, s)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you want to use `Stream`s then you can write:

```
private boolean isStatusAvailable(List<Hierarchy> hierarchyList, ResultStatus status, int i) {
  Hierarchy hierarchy = hierarchyList.get(i + 1);
  return Stream.of(status, SUCCESS, PEND).anyMatch(s -> isContainsStatus(hierarchy, s));
}
```